# how create a makefile for program.c and how to compile and execute in Real Time Application Interface

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, real-time, rtai

I have a   `hollowworld.c`  :

```
/* hello.c */
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int init_module(void)
{
  printk("Hello world!\n"); /* printk = kernel printf, to the console */

  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
  printk("Goodbye world!\n");

  return;
}
```

how create a makefile for program.c and how to compile and execute in Real Time Application Interface ?

Comment: This is a kernel module, what do you mean by "Real Time Application"?

Answer (score 2):

To compile a kernel module, refer to other drivers in the kernel source tree. You will find it the Makefile as simple as one line in your example:

```
obj-M += hollowworld.o
```

Comment: Real Time Application Interface

Comment: yes, ok, but what does that has anything to do with the kernel module code you posted?